# How to color adjustments for button in the stylesheet Opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, opencart2.x

In Opencart 2.0.3.1,

I've changed most of the colors for menu, links, add to cart button, etc. in the stylesheet.css, but I can't seem to alter the background blue color when the Add to Cart button loads something into the cart (and a few other "action" buttons, continue, login, etc.).

This may be because it's in the bootstrap.css, but I was wondering if anyone is familiar with how bootstrap would handle this "action" button background color, and help me locate the class to alter?

Comment: instead of changing the original class, make a class with the same name in your own stylesheet and put there the tweaks in, this means, if your own stylesheet breaks, your elements still have a visual appearance, instead of breaking down, when you modify it.

Answer (score 0):

The "add to cart" button has a class "btn-primary". It is blue in color. You can remove it and give your custom class with any background color. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following css for overwrite bootstrap css of primary button in stylesheet.css.

Add below css in your stylesheet.css (You can change your color code instead of following color code.)

```
.btn-primary {
    background-color: #428bca;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked, provided by virtual7 at freelancer.com

In the stylesheet.css it was like this: .btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary[disabled] { background-color: #567237; background-position: 0 -15px; }
background-position: 0 -15px; had to be removed